# Choice element in XML Schema with any order, any number and "one element restriction"?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

What I'm trying to do is, declare an parent element called "data", which are having 6 sub element of these one element are conditional that means one element is appear only and only one time and other can appear any number of times with any order.

```
Example:

<data>
   <Child1>text1</Child1>
   <Child2>text1</Child2>
   <Child3>text1</Child3>
   <Child4>text1</Child4>
   <Child5>text1</Child5>
   <Child6>text1</Child6> <!-- Only one times-->


</data>
```

1 : All element can appear in any order and any number of times.

2 : Child6 is appear only one time.

**XSD Code**

```
<xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sequence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                            <xs:element ref="Child1" />
                            <xs:element ref="Child1" />
                            <xs:element ref="Child3" />
                            <xs:element ref="Child4" />                          
                            <xs:element ref="Child5" />
                            <xs:element ref="Child6" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>

                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Please suggest me how can i do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD below will validate according to these rules:

- Allows `Child1` to `Child5` elements in any order, all optional, repeating any number of times.
- Allows only *one* `Child6` element which, if present, must be positioned *after* all the other elements.

```
<xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Child1" />
                <xs:element name="Child2" />
                <xs:element name="Child3" />
                <xs:element name="Child4" />                          
                <xs:element name="Child5" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Child6" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

To allow `Child6` to also appear anywhere, you can use `xs:all` but you'll need a **XSD 1.1** compatible parser since XSD 1.0 parsers won't allow elements in `xsd:all` to have unbounded occurrences:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Child1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Child2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Child3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Child4" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />                          
                <xs:element name="Child5" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Child6" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

You *can* achieve something in between with XSD 1.0, but you'll have to decide if it is worth writing a more complex and less reusable schema to allow for the flexibility you want in placing your elements.

Comment: Sir I want to Child1 to Child6 in any order including exactly on occurrence of Child6 Thank you.

Comment: Are you designing this XSD? If so, it would be better practice to place the non-repeating element in another context (such as wrapping the repeating ones, and having the non-repeating one as a sibling. If you really need to validate any-order unbounded elements mixed up with a restricted one it won't be so trivial (unless you can use XSD 1.1 which supports `xs:all` with unbounded elements). I'll edit the answer with some alternatives.

Comment: Yes i am designing  this xsd, can you please provide me a simple example ?